# jquery: menu show at mouseover

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img.menu_class').click(function () {
    $('ul.the_menu').slideToggle('medium');
    });
    $('.img.menu_class').mouseover(function() {
    $('ul.the_menu').slideToggle('medium');
    });
});
```

I've added this mouseover, but it doesnt work, only if i click.. What have i done wrong?

Comment: you have $('.img.menu_class') and $('img.menu_class'). make sure both are same and reffering to the correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` insted of `mouseover` because `mouseover` is triggered every time the pointer moves into the child element and `mouseenter` only when the pointer moves into the bound element.

```
$('img.menu_class').bind("mouseenter", function () {
    $('ul.the_menu').slideToggle('medium');
});
$('ul.the_menu').bind("mouseleave", function () {
    $('ul.the_menu').slideToggle('medium');
});
```

Comment: Your new edited code works the same as Jacob´s, issue: menu slides up when you try to markover a <li> link

Comment: I guess that will work now. It will help if you post your html too

Comment: It works now great.. i tested in FF and IE, but then in IE why do i need to accept "ActiveX controller warning" in order to have it working?